# This call of a method should be causing an IndexOutOfBoundsException. How come it doesn't?

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a simple method that gets a Date as an argument and then decides if it in winter or not, returning true or false, respectively.

I'm passing the "date" 2012-13-01 as argument. It's clear the array doesn't have a 13th element, how come I still get a return value (which is false)?

```
package calculation;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Calculation {
    public static boolean isWinter(Date date){

        final byte winter[] = {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1};
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);

        System.out.println();
        return (winter[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)] == 0) ? false : true;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2012-13-01");
            System.out.println(date.toString());
            System.out.println(isWinter(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Date is just a long. It's the #parse where the issue is.

Comment: Did you look at the value of `date` in a debugger? Do that and you'll understand immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` is rolling over the 13 to mean January of the subsequent year.

You can see this in your own output:

> Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2013

When you later create and query the `Calendar` for a month, it returns 0, which is in the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing a date that appears to have an invalid month, 13, but by default `SimpleDateFormat` is "lenient", meaning it will interpret month 13 as the 1st month of the following year.  The actual date parsed is January 1st, 2013.

There is no `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because the month is actually `0` for January (months are 0-based in `Calendar`s and `Date`s).

Answer (score 0):

As from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)), `parse` *uses the calendar to produce a Date*. By looking at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) of the calendar, we find that:

> Calendar has two modes for interpreting the calendar fields, lenient and non-lenient. When a Calendar is in lenient mode, it accepts a wider range of calendar field values than it produces.

That means that it accepts `13` as a month and simply wrap over to `1`, thus setting February as its month, for being lenient is the default mode for the  `SimpleDateFormat` class. In fact, from the above linked documentation, you find that:

> By default, parsing is lenient

Use `setLenient(false)` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) for the documentation) if you want it to throw an exception in such a case.